# Setting up Cassandra on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cassandra, ide, cloud9-ide, cqlsh

I've followed these instructions to install Cassandra: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html 
When I do `$ cqlsh` terminal replies me with

```
Connection error: Could not connect to localhost:9160
```

I read that the issue might be with configuration file `cassandra.yaml`
However, I turned out I can't access it. My etc/cassandra folder is empty: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V1LH.png)
How to access `cassandra.yaml`?
Where is cassandra is stored in my project? 
Is there a way to check if Cassandra is actually set up in project?

Answer (score 1):

The image you have attached is showing the `~/.cassandra` directory off of your home dir.  That's not the same as`/etc/cassandra`.  You should be able to confirm this with the following command:

```
$ ls -al /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 cassandra cassandra 43985 Mar 11 12:46 /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

To verify if Cassandra is even running, this should work for you if you have successfully completed the packaged install:

```
$ sudo service cassandra status
```

Otherwise, simply running this should work, too:

```
$ ps -ef | grep cassandra
```

When you set up Cassandra, you'll want to set the `listen_address` and `rpc_address` to the machine's hostname or IP.  They're set to `localhost` by default, so if it's running `cqlsh` should connect to that automatically.

My guess is that Cassandra is not starting for you.  Check the system.log file, which (for the packaged install) is stored in `/var/logs/cassandra`:

```
$ cat /var/log/cassandra/system.log
```

Check out that file, and you might find some clues as to what is happening here.

Also, did you really install Cassandra 2.0?  That version has been deprecated, so for a new install you shouldn't go any lower than Cassandra 2.1.